# Theme customization lost when rendering to string on client

Tags: css, material-ui, render-to-string, jss

I'm using material-ui-next and have customized the theme to use my color styles and a custom font. eg. Typography subheading

I'm now attempting to render a component to string for use in a google maps info window. The default material-ui theme is available in the callback `styles` object passed to withStyles, but none of my customizations are available on the `theme` argument in the `styles` callback nor are they applied. The rendered string renders otherwise correctly (albeit w/o events which I sorta expected).

More concisely, when rendering normally, customizations apply. When rendering to string, they do not.

A simple example would be a component that runs withStyles correctly, but return the div instead of the target component ala:

`let output = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(component);
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: output}} />`

Any tips how I can get my theme customizations to be passed into the withStyles callback `theme` argument?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make a parent component that renders the target component as a child of the ThemeProvider. There are still no event handlers (as expected), but the theme customizations apply.

Here's the solution:

MyThemeProvider.js (component can also easily be reused for SSR)

```
export default function MyThemeProvider({children}) {
  const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
    typography: {
      fontFamily: '"Bryant", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif',
    },
    palette: {
      primary: customBluePalette,
    },
    // ... 
  });
  return (<MuiThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>{ children }</MuiThemeProvider>);
}
```

MapInfoWindowContent.js (here, this only really exists to wrap VenueRenderer with our theme provider)

```
import MyThemeProvider from '../MyThemeProvider';
import VenueRenderer from '../VenueRenderer';
export default function MapInfoWindowContent({resource}) {
  return (<MyThemeProvider><VenueRenderer resource={resource} /></MyThemeProvider>);
}
```

VenueRenderer (the styled class - can be used independently of MapInfoWindowContent too)

```
const styles = (theme) => {
    // theme.palette.primary['500'] comes from customBluePalette so the injection worked.
}
// ...
export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(VenueRenderer);
```

In some other component that needs the HTML str

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import MapInfoWindowContent from '../MapInfoWindowContent';

let infoWindowComponent = (<MapInfoWindowContent resource={ ... }/>);
let output = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(infoWindowComponent);
// output will have correctly injected classNames that contain customizations
```